# Getting a list of images on web page with image size

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I frequently have to do optimization tasks on websites, and I typically start with very large images ( Example 2mb ) and go from there. Pingdom speed test use to allow you to sort by images and size but now prevent this. Does anyone know if there is a website or a console script I can run to give me a simple list of every image on a webpage along with how large that image is?

I searched for this but can't find much because most people are looking for dimensions of an image and not size.

Comment: Can't you go to your network tab, filter by images, and sort by size?

Comment: I can but the pain point here is that I get a lot of "(memory cache)" listed under the size, even when I disable cache. I can work around this by doing incognito but it would be more convenient having a saved snippet I could just run or a website I could use.

Comment: In FF at least, I see cached only under `Transferred`, not `Size`

Comment: Try gtmetrix.com, enter your site > scan > waterfall tab > image tab and then sort by size.